# Cannot get Jep to work with Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, macos

For one of my projects I have the need to mix Java with some well established Python code, so I turned my attention to JEP as this seems to be the perfect solution to my problem. I am using Java 1.8 and Python 3.6 on Mac OSX, and my Java IDE is Eclipse.

Unfortunately, I struggle to get this to work, mainly because I am really a newby I think.

In Eclipse, I have set my Build path to include the 'jep-3.7.1.jar', and I have also linked the path to the native '.so' file to 'Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep/'. So it seems like I have done everything I need, but when I try to run a simple code that calls for a Jep object I get the following naste exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep/jep.cpython-36m-darwin.so: dlopen(/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep/jep.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep/jep.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1861)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at jep.Jep.<clinit>(Jep.java:217)
    at mixingPython.mixJvcPyth.getDataFromPython(mixJvcPyth.java:11)
    at mixingPython.mixJvcPyth.main(mixJvcPyth.java:29)/
```

I am sure that this is basic, but if anyone could help it would be great!

Cedric

Comment: Reading the exception line makes it seem it can't find a method because "libpython3.6m.dylib" isn't loaded. Are you sure you have a complete python package with all libraries and of the right name?

Comment: Thanks Miekpeeps. I actually have 2, not 1, "libpython3.6m.dylin", one at anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.3-h6804ab2_0/lib/ and one at anaconda3/lib/

Could that be the problem?

Comment: It's possible there may be a version difference between the two libraries. If so, those two libraries aren't exactly the same and may be missing some methods your app is trying to access. The exception says "Reason: image not found" on "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep/jep.cpython-36m-darwin.so". It sounds like the file is missing.

Comment: Ok thanks. I know too little to fix that one I am afraid! I also noticed the bit about the Rpath. Thought mixing Java with Python would be easier than that, so I am proven wrong. ;)

Comment: Try setting the environment variables DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory where libpython is.  The error implies it found the libjep but can't find the libpython that jep is depending on.  In Eclipse you can set environment variables through Run -> Run Configurations -> Environment tab.